# Conectarme a wifi en un Linux con Virtualbox

Tags: linux, redes, virtualbox

acabo de instalar Linux en una máquina virtual y esta está conectada a internet a través de cable LAN y necesito que se conecte por wifi y me muestre las redes wifi desde la máquina virtual, hice los procedimientos para que se conecte por wifi y me sigue saliendo como si fuera por LAN y al intentar probar me sale que no reconoce ninguna interfaz inalámbrica. Adjunto la configuración que hice en virtual box y como se mira en la máquina virtual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui la configuracion para la LAN (esto no lo he tocado)
y aqui con la manera para que use la tarjeta de red y está conectada a la misma tarjeta de red con la que en mi computadora estoy conectado por forma wifi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi me sale en la maquina virtual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si quieres configurar una red WiFi **dentro** de la máquina virtual deberás pasarle un dispositivo WiFi a través de USB o PCI "paso a través". Lo más sencillo es usar un dispositivo WiFi USB y presentarlo a la máquina virtual a través del menú "Dispositivos > USB > ...", siempre y cuando tengas instalados el [pack de extensiones](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: ¿Qué tal llevas este problema? ¿Lo solucionaste?

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo o configuración de tu red, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).